# Were the Fal'dorei modified by the Old Gods like the Naga were?

Tags: warcraft

In *World of Warcraft: Legion* we run into several new varieties of elves that happened to survive the War of the Ancients. One sub-species were called the 'fal'dorei': half-elf, half-spider (think driders from D&D). They were mutated as they retreated from the destruction of the Well of Eternity. This sounds very similar to another situation: the naga. They were sinking and an Old God (N'Zoth) had transformed them into their serpentine forms.

However, when playing through the quests that involved them, I didn't see any information. Is there something I'm missing, were these spider elf hybrids created by the old gods, or did something else mutate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Valewalker Farodin, they were transformed by the arcan'dor, the magical tree at the root (aha) of his part in the Suramar quest chain. This occurred some time after the War of the Ancients, when Suramar was under its shield.

The relevant quotes come from the quest "Fragments of Disaster":

> Many years ago, exiles from the shielded city [Suramar] came to rest here. Pity took root in my heart. I shared with them the ancient gift: an arcan'dor. For a time it sustained them. For a time, they were safe. It would not last. The tree became unstable. The arcan'dor died. In a flash of wild magic, the inhabitants of Falanaar were twisted. The fal'dorei are my failure. I will *not* fail again.

It's not entirely impossible that the Old Gods had some hand in it, but Farodin's account suggests it was the arcan'dor alone.

Comment: Plus one for Pun!